# Особые кнопки в CodeGear  C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, c++

Как создавать в билдере кнопки, стиль которых будет отличатся от обычного стиля Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще можно использовать [сторонние компоненты](http://www.alphaskins.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте изображение TImage (или TBitmap - плохо помню). Сделайте несколько изображений на несколько состояний кнопки. Далее просто обрабатываете событие нажатие и меняете изображение на необходимое.
Пример: http://www.yevol.com/bcb/Lesson21.htm